# GRUB Rescue Command Problem

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot, grubrescue

I did originally have Ubuntu installed on my Laptop, however I then installed Joli OS, since I did not want it any more, I formatted the disk which had Joli OS on, thinking that it would revert back to the original Ubuntu boot loader. However when I boot my laptop, it comes up with:
`GRUB Rescue >`
Any ideas?
Many thanks

Comment: Boot from a LiveCD/USB of Ubuntu and choose "Try Ubuntu" , then open a terminal and follow the instructions from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#A2nd_option_:_install_Boot-Repair_in_Ubuntu).

Comment: @NikTh I have made an install disk but it still goes straight to the GRUB Rescue page, I have changed my boot order but still no joy